# Upgrade / Migrate from Joomla 1.5.26 to Joomla 3.0.1

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I have a joomla 1.5.26 site and want to upgrade over to Joomla 3.0.1. Is that possible? If so, what are the steps? I am looking for an installer like JUpgrade to do this.

I realize that it is a  2 step process:
   a. Migrate from Joomla 1.5.26 to Joomla 2.5

b. Migrate from Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3.0.1

Use `JUpgrade` for both the steps after backing up your files using `Akeeba / XCloner` component

Am I right or am I missing a step?

Comment: I know the tool that allows you to upgrade your tool from 1.5.26 to 3.0.x directly without switching to joomla 2.5. here's video tutorial on how to proceed with the upgrading http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5wHY6HA9HI
But this tool doesn't upgrade your template and extensions to the version you upgrade to. SO, you have to install the new ones. However, this is reliable tool while speaking about the website elements and it takes really little time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to stick with Joomla 2.5 as it is recommended till 2014. Here is statement quoted by joomla .org

"Joomla 2.5 is the Long Term Support (LTS) version of Joomla. That means that it has already undergone many months of real-world testing. Joomla 2.5 is stable, tested and reliable. Joomla 2.5 is the version being used by Joomla.org."

Answer (score 3):

As you already know, you have to upgrade to Joomla 2.5 first, then to 3.x

Once you have upgraded to Joomla 2.5, download the [2.5-3.0.1 Update Patch](http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/17575/76729/Joomla_3.0.1-Stable-Update_Package.zip) and upload to the root folder in your FTP and extract it.

Of course, take a backup of your site before uploading the patch.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a huge step for your website. If I were you I would upgrade to 2.5.

**Joomla! 3.0 is really a short time release** and in a couple of months you will have to upgrade again to 3.1.

**Joomla! 2.5 is the current stable version.** I would recommend it!

[Joomla! Download](http://www.joomla.org/download.html) page also states:

- Joomla! 2.5.x (Recommended for most websites)
- 3.0.x (Recommended for developers and early adopters)

Also it would be a good idea to have a look at the **[Joomla! 3.0. FAQ](http://community.joomla.org/blogs/community/1683-joomla-30-faq.html)**

Comment: "you will have to upgrade again" - but the upgrade process is being made *much* easier, isn't it? I thought this was one of the key benefits of Joomla 3.x

Comment: "much easier", it's true, this is also the promise from Joomla!. But it's still an upgrade, things change, bugs appear, some are not solved yet. (which means testing, repairing problems, investing time).

Answer (score 1):

Whether to do 2.5 or 3 depends totally on whether you are migrating third party extensions that are Joomla 3 ready or not. If you are just using the core, Joomla 3 is a simple update  from 2.5 except that you will need to update your template ... but the fact is the coming from 1.5 you need to change your template for either 2.5 or 3, so you might as well go to J3 instead of having to do it again.  Personally, unless I needed extensions I would just do J3 for any new site since you will have 3 years of support and be mobile ready. One thing you'll find about 2.5 and forward is that you need many fewer extensions than in the past.

The biggest problem with migration from 1.5 is that 2.5+ requires the asset table to be correct and in some cases JUpdate still seems to make it incorrect (generally if you had a third party extension that was using the content table). If your table is a reasonable size you can do a visual scan and make sure it looks sane. There are some ways to fix broken assets but never do it directly. There's a commercial product called ACL Manager that has asset repair and I also have an application that will run simple repairs that you could try https://github.com/elinw/AssetFix.

Comment: In some Joomla docs it says J3 will have only seven months of support (i.e. http://docs.joomla.org/Release_and_support_cycle), sometimes I hear it's three years (http://docs.joomla.org/How_long_is_each_Joomla!_version_supported%3F). Or is the solution that 3.0 has only seven months but if I keep upgrading to 3.1, 3.5 that will amount to three years? If so, will a 3.0 extension keep working in 3.5? Clarification greatly appreciated.

Comment: J3 will have 3 years or more of support. 3.0 will have 6 months, 3.1 6 months etc. They are all the same major releases so extensions which are properly coded for 3.0 will work for all.