# Upgrading joomla 1.5.25 to new version

Tags: joomla1.5

I am doing some work for my brother's website. It is a joomla site(1.5.25). There is no database or log-in , or anything, it is just a basic click and get information about the types of recruitment he does. I think we should upgrade to a newer version of joomla. If anyone has some experience with joomla could walk me through the process, or suggest a place to read up on it , that would be greatly appreciated. I think, think?, it would be fairly painless because all the site does is display articles, but I don't wanna loose any of the modules that were  built be previous developers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrade / Migrate from Joomla 1.5.26 to Joomla 3.0.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015859/upgrade-migrate-from-joomla-1-5-26-to-joomla-3-0-1)

Answer (score 0):

Its not that easy as you think. To many things have changed for Joomla 3.4.
Very likely that your template will not work anymore. You need to check that first. Even when you think that its a standard Joomla site you might find several added plugins, like SEF, or editor. Check through the component and the plugins and make sure there is not one that is 3rd party.

If all that is fine then you can use a migrator component that you can get for free. Your would install the new Joomla 3 in a subfolder below your current Joomla, install the migration component and that would copy all tables, articles and modules.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I decided to play it safe, and leave well enough alone. "If it ain't broke, don't fix it"

Comment: I fully agree, I migrated several old 1.5 sites and I try not do do any more, Its just a lot more work then you think.